# Postgres add additional field to json payload index within an array prior to inserting as record set into database

Tags: postgresql

I'm creating a stored procedure in postgres which takes a json and inserts into a table by performing a json_to_recordset command.
Prior to inserting the record set into a SQL table with that command I want to add an additional field as a index to the json in the json array.
Is this possible?

For each index in the array I want to add       "current_status": "pending"

```
[
    {
        "batch_id": "40",
        "state_id": "10"
    },
    {
        "batch_id": "40",
        "state_id": "10"
    }
]
```

after

```
[
    {
        "batch_id": "40",
        "state_id": "10",
        "current_status": "pending"
    },
    {
        "batch_id": "40",
        "state_id": "10"
        "current_status": "pending"
    }
]
```

Another option is updating the only NEW records in the table after the fact.
I'm new to postgres and have been reading through the documentation.

Comment: If you are using it in a `json_to_recordset()` call, then I assume you are writing these objects as individual rows with the values in `batch_id` and `state_id` columns.  If that is the case, then what do you plan to do with the modified json after adding the `current_status` keys?

Comment: All that matters is that the current_status field is added to the SQL table along side batch_id, and state_id. I'm trying to perform this stored procedure with as few steps as possible to reduce overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your added comment, the `current_status = 'pending'` should be added as part of the insert into your target table instead of appending the key to the json objects.

```
insert into target_table (batch_id, state_id, current_status)
select batch_id, state_id, 'pending' as current_status
  from json_to_recordset(<json>) as x(batch_id text, state_id text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Mike's correct answer, in the case we want to modify existing tables with json arrays to include the status we may:

```
-- First create the table
CREATE TABLE myJson AS

SELECT '[
  {
    "batch_id": "40",
    "state_id": "10"
  },
  {
    "batch_id": "50",
    "state_id": "60"
  }
]'::json js;

WITH unnest_and_concat AS (
  SELECT json_array_elements(js)::jsonb || json_build_object('current_status', 'pending')::jsonb jee
  FROM myJson)
SELECT json_agg(jee)::json
FROM unnest_and_concat;
```

Of course this is only intended to work for a table with these rows (for illustration). If the objective is to update the entire table then we can do that (ideally with a `LATERAL JOIN`) mixed with an update statement. Looks like:

```
UPDATE myJson
SET old_col=new_col
FROM <insert subquery or table>
WHERE myJson.id = new_table.id;
```

Nevertheless, I would recommend modifying upon insert rather than updating.